# Проблема при чтении из бинарного файла в C

Tags: c, файлы, binary

Программа для работы со списками студентов. Она содержит структуры:

```
typedef unsigned short __uint16;
typedef struct __marks {
    __uint16 Informatika;
    __uint16 Algebra;
    __uint16 Matanaliz;
    __uint16 Fizika;
} Marks;

typedef struct __students {
    char *SecondName;
    char *FirstName;
    __uint16 Age;
    Marks Object;
} Students;
```

При чтении из бинарного файла, в котором содержится 120 записей, считываются не все структуры.

[image: Вот скриншотик]

Запись в бинарный файл проходит следующим образом:

Записываем кол-во записей -> Дальше по циклу(Запись кол-во символов фамилии(Secondname) -> Запись SecondName -> аналогично для FirstName -> возраст -> оценки)
Чтение проходит соответственным образом, но где-то есть косяк, и я не могу его найти в режиме отладки поэтому прошу помощи.

Код записи в бинарный файл:

```
void WriteInBinFileStudents(Students *Group, __uint16 Count)
{
    if (Count == 0)
    {
        printf("Список пуст!\n");
        return;
    }

    errno_t err;
    FILE *file;
    size_t strsize;

    char *filename;

    printf("Введите имя для сохранения в бинарном файле: ");
    filename = ScanName();

    err = fopen_s(&file, filename, "wb");
    if (err != 0 || file == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    fwrite(&Count, sizeof(__uint16), 1, file);

    for (__uint16 i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
    {
        strsize = strlen(Group[i].SecondName);
        fwrite(&strsize, sizeof(size_t), 1, file);
        fwrite(Group[i].SecondName, sizeof(char), strsize, file);

        strsize = strlen(Group[i].FirstName);
        fwrite(&strsize, sizeof(size_t), 1, file);
        fwrite(Group[i].FirstName, sizeof(char), strsize, file);

        fwrite(&Group[i].Age, sizeof(__uint16), 1, file);

        fwrite(&Group[i].Object.Informatika, sizeof(__uint16), 1, file);
        fwrite(&Group[i].Object.Algebra, sizeof(__uint16), 1, file);
        fwrite(&Group[i].Object.Matanaliz, sizeof(__uint16), 1, file);
        fwrite(&Group[i].Object.Fizika, sizeof(__uint16), 1, file);
    }

    fclose(file);
    free(filename);

    printf("Список студентов успешно сохранен!\n\n");
}
```

Код для чтения:

```
Students *ReadFromBinFileStudents(Students *Group, __uint16 *Count)
{
    Students *NewGroup;
    FILE *file;
    size_t strsize;
    char *filename;

    printf("Введите имя бинарного файла для загрузки: ");
    filename = ScanName();

    if (FileCheck(filename) == -1)
        return Group;

    if (*Count != 0)
    {
        for (__uint16 i = 0; i < *Count; ++i)
            MemStudentsFree(Group, i);
        free(Group);
        *Count = 0;
    }

    fopen_s(&file, filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    fread_s(Count, sizeof(__uint16), sizeof(__uint16), 1, file);
    NewGroup = (Students*)malloc(*Count * sizeof(Students));
    if (NewGroup == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for (__uint16 i = 0; i < *Count; ++i)
    {
        fread_s(&strsize, sizeof(size_t), sizeof(size_t), 1, file);
        NewGroup[i].SecondName = (char*)malloc((strsize + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (NewGroup[i].SecondName == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        fread_s(NewGroup[i].SecondName, strsize * sizeof(char), sizeof(char), strsize, file);
        NewGroup[i].SecondName[strsize] = 0;

        fread_s(&strsize, sizeof(size_t), sizeof(size_t), 1, file);
        NewGroup[i].FirstName = (char*)malloc((strsize + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (NewGroup[i].FirstName == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        fread_s(NewGroup[i].FirstName, strsize * sizeof(char), sizeof(char), strsize, file);
        NewGroup[i].FirstName[strsize] = 0;

        fread_s(&NewGroup[i].Age, sizeof(__uint16), sizeof(__uint16), 1, file);

        fread_s(&NewGroup[i].Object.Informatika, sizeof(__uint16), sizeof(__uint16), 1, file);
        fread_s(&NewGroup[i].Object.Algebra, sizeof(__uint16), sizeof(__uint16), 1, file);
        fread_s(&NewGroup[i].Object.Matanaliz, sizeof(__uint16), sizeof(__uint16), 1, file);
        fread_s(&NewGroup[i].Object.Fizika, sizeof(__uint16), sizeof(__uint16), 1, file);
    }

    fclose(file);
    free(filename);

    PrintStudents(NewGroup, *Count);

    return NewGroup;
}
```

Остальные функции которые здесь использовались:

```
#define LIST "%hu. %s %s\nВозраст: %hu\nОценки: Информатика - %hu, Алгебра - %hu, Мат.Анализ - %hu, Физика - %hu\n\n"
void MemStudentsFree(Students *Group, __int16 index)
{
    if (Group[index].SecondName == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    else
        free(Group[index].SecondName);

    if (Group[index].FirstName == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    else
        free(Group[index].FirstName);
}
void PrintStudents(Students *Group, __uint16 Count)
{
    if (Count == 0)
    {
        printf("Список пуст!\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Список студентов:\n\n");

    for (__uint16 i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
    {
        printf(LIST, i + 1, Group[i].SecondName, Group[i].FirstName, Group[i].Age,
            Group[i].Object.Informatika, Group[i].Object.Algebra, Group[i].Object.Matanaliz, Group[i].Object.Fizika);
    }
}
```

Comment: ссылки читать нельзя - они не сохраняют содержимое.

Comment: Попробуйте `char *SecondName` заменить на `char SecondName[100]` (и FirstName тоже)

Comment: @nick-n-a А где вы тут увидели чтение ссылок?

Comment: А как вызываются эти функции?

Comment: @nick_n_a Мне необходимо использовать кучу, а не стек.

Comment: С ходу, пишите структуру Marks целиком в файл, и читайте тоже, нет смысла её писать по полям.

Comment: Да и структуру Students можно писать полностью, оверхеад на две ссылки char* невелик. В структуре можно завести два поля, размер строки в SecondName, FirstName. Заполнять можно заранее. Сами строки писать после структуры, по очереди. И читать соответственно целиком структуру, выделять память в ней для строк, и читать их туда.

Comment: А ещё правильней, завести отдельную структуру типа: `typedef struct __mystr { char* str, size_t sz; } mystr;` и использовать её для полей SecondName, FirstName

Comment: По позже выберу время, набросаю пример, как оптимальней читать/писать

Comment: Будьте добры, пример файла для чтения приведите : хотелось бы потестить)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При чтении файла попробуй бинарный режим, так как ты считываешь много чисел (не текст). 
`fopen_s(&file, filename, "r");` -> `fopen_s(&file, filename, "rb");`

Comment: Не играет роли в данном случае

Comment: Точно, совсем про это забыл, спасибо, все заработало